How can I analyse this circuit with two port network here?
The following is a figure from 8.72 in Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit, page 319:

The author used Bode analysis in the textbook. I am wondering whether I can solve it with two port network analysis.


$$A_{v,open} = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = -\frac{g_{m1} R_F R_D} {R_S  +R_F}$$

$$\beta = g_{21}=\frac{V_2}{V_1} |_{I_2 = 0} = 1$$
$$LG = A_{v,open} \beta = -\frac{g_{m1} R_F R_D} {R_S  +R_F}$$
The author has this loop gain instead:
$$LG = \frac{g_{m1} R_S R_D} {R_D + R_S  +R_F}$$

Can you change your equations to match the figure?  What is V2?  I2??

My question to you is this: if you don't dispute what the author says and your answer is different, what is your question really about? On the other hand, if you do dispute what the author says then, which part of the solution given by the author do you find a problem with?

@ScottSeidman I posted new figure for this

@Andyaka Why is my LG different from the author? Who is correct?

In your circuit, You need two port parameters such as V1, I1,  Vout, Iout  ... You need to calculate the currents using ideal op amp rules.

This is the classic case where Miller's theorem of voltages (at the ports of a quadripole) is applied.

@Franc Can you show me a circuit diagram with loading effect?

@kile Search online for Miller effect, you will find many examples.

@Franc Can it be analysed with https://i.imgur.com/9JndRfb.png?
